# Unable to get id of an element

Tags: jquery

I'm unable to get id of the clicked element using `this` as it returns 'undefined'. I am also unable to pass any parameter to the function.

What am I missing here? If I use `class` name instead of pointing to the element as `$(this)`, I can get the first item's id but it doesn't work if I point using $(this).

```
if(data && data[0].type) { 
    var parameter="type";
    typeMsg +="Car Type : ";
    typeMsg +="<table>";
    $.each(data[0].type , function( index, value ){
       console.log(value);
       typeMsg +="<tr><td>"+ value +"</td><td class='text-center'><a href='#' id='"+value+"' onclick='deleteThis(parameter)' class='delete'><img src='../img/cross.png'></a></td></tr>"; 
    });
    typeMsg +="</table>";
 }

 function deleteThis(param) {
    console.log(param);         //outputs nothing
    var deleteId = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(deleteId);      //says undefined
 }
```

Comment: Kindly paste ur HTML code that is related to this..

Comment: @Arcanyx, I dont use html here..but the html is created in jquery which I pasted above.

Comment: Do not generate markup like that, and do not use inline `onClick` handlers - you are including jQuery for a reason : ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of parameter send `this` with `onclick`, It will get you the current element and you can get the id of the same then

```js
function deleteThis(param,text) {
  alert(text); 
  var deleteId = $(param).attr("id");
  alert(deleteId)
  console.log(deleteId);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' id='qwe' onclick="deleteThis(this,'tushar')">click</a>
```

Comment: this works..thanks...how do I also pass a string in the deleteThis function as a second parameter?

Comment: @Vani : Updated Plz check